# Python function and operation

Tags: python, function

Why the n changes after executing the second function?
I have no idea why it's happening. I didn't even use global?
Is there any differences between a = a * 2 and a *= 2?
Please help me out here.

```
def f(a):
  print(f"Before: {a}")
  a = a * 2
  print(f"After: {a}")

def d(a):
  print(f"Before: {a}")
  a *= 2
  print(f"After: {a}")


n = [1,2,3,4]

print("First fun")
f(n)
print(f"  n: {n}")

print("Second fun")
d(n)
print(f"  n: {n}")
```

Output:

```
First fun
Before: [1, 2, 3, 4]
After: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  n: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Second fun
Before: [1, 2, 3, 4]
After: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  n: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: because augmented assignment operators will work in-place, conventionally. `a = a * 2` does not work in-place, it creates a new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, `a` and `n` are references to the same list. `a * 2` creates a *new* list; when you assign that to `a`, `a` no longer refers to the same list as `n`. `a *= 2`, on the other hand, modifies the list referenced by `a` *in place*, so the change is visible from `n` as well.